# Apex code to create a folder in box.com with a trigger

Tags: salesforce, box-api, force.com

I've embedded a box visualforce page on an object that displays the contents of the linked box folder. However the user must click to create the folder if one does not exist.

I'm trying to write a trigger that creates links box folder when the new record is created, and then populates a folder structure beneath it.

From what I have read there was a private api call in box-api 1.0 but that there was something being delivered in the 2.0 api. that's been released (for a while) but I can't find it.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Box hasn't yet converted the private V1 API to V2 and released it publicly. We don't yet have a definitive timeline for doing so, but we're working on it.